# Cant input + as operator

Tags: c

I'm not sure if some of this code is in the wrong format, first few days learning. Any help appreciated

```
At line:1 char:2
+ +
+  ~
Missing expression after unary operator '+'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(int num1,int num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}

int subtraction(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1-num2;
}

int multiplication(int num1,int num2)
{
    return num1*num2;   
}

float division(int num1,int  num2)
{
    return (float)num1/num2;
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char operator;
    
    printf("insert a number 1 here: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1); //store number in num1

    printf("insert a number 2 here: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2); //store number in num2
    
    printf("Would you like to\n Add(+)\nSubtract(-)\nMultiply(*)\nDevide(/)?\nEnter symbol here: ");
    scanf("%c", &operator); // should i be using %c or something to get the operator from the user?

    if(operator == '+') 
    {
        int result1 = addition(num1,num2); //not sure if this is in the correct format.
        printf("The number after addition is: %d", result1);
    }

//i know using cases would be easier for creating a calculator like this but im learning functions rn
//not completed
}
```

Comment: That error comes from PowerShell. It sounds like you're trying to run the C program as a PowerShell script.

Comment: Can you tell us how you compile or execute this code? Or how do you get the error message?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int addition(int num1,int num2)
    {

        return num1+num2;

    }

    int subtraction(int num1, int num2)
    {

        return num1-num2;

    }

    int multiplication(int num1,int num2)
    {

        return num1*num2;   

    }

    float division(int num1,int  num2)
    {

        return (float)num1/num2;

    }


int main()
{
    int i;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char operator;
    

    
    printf("insert a number 1 here: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1); //store number in num1

    printf("insert a number 2 here: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2); //store number in num2
    
    printf("Would you like to\nAdd(+)\nSubtract(-)\nMultiply(*)\nDevide(/)?\nEnter symbol here: ");
    scanf(" %c", &operator); // should i be using %c or something to get the operator from the user?
    

    if(operator =='+') 
    {

       int result1 = addition(num1,num2); //not sure if this is in the correct format.
       printf("The number after addition is: %d", result1);

    }

//i know using cases would be easier for creating a calculator like this but im learning functions rn
//not completed

  
    


}
```

this must work just needed a space in the scanf.
in the scanf you used for the operator you needed a space before the %c otherwise wont work.

Comment: Well, that's the *next* problem, anyway.